# Scala stub class with generics

Tags: scala, generics, scalatest

I am trying to stub a case class which has structure similar to below code.

```
case class Employee[T](name:T) {
  def greet(str:String):String = {
    "Hi, "+ str + ":" + name
  }

  def farewell(str:String):String = {
    "Bye, "+ str + ":" + name
  }
}
```

However, when creating a stub like this:
`val emp = stub[Employee[String]]`,
gives the following error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : T
 required: String
  val emp = stub[Employee[String]]
```

How can i Stub this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stubbing cases classes is usually avoided but assuming you are using ScalaMock try extending it first with some defaults, for example

```
class StrEmployee extends Employee[String](null)
val emp = stub[StrEmployee]
(emp.greet _).when("aa").returns("bb")
assert(emp.greet("aa") == "bb")
```